# How do you get the DOM element of a component you just rendered in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class where I render a modal, like this:

```
import Modal from 'Modal';

export default class SomeClass extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
       modal: null
    }

    
  }

  render() {
    return (
     
        <Modal />

    );
  }
}
```

I want to initialize the modal as a [Bootstrap modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/) so that I can call methods like `.show()` from `SomeClass` and have the modal show up. I need to thus call:

```
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'), options)
```

And save it's state, but I don't want to use `getElementById`... I would rather just reference it directly. How would I do this in React?

Comment: The answer is refs, but you shouldn't do that. React isn't a wrapper for vanilla JS, you should use this instead: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/

Comment: This page uses Bootstrap 4 (I'm using Bootstrap 5) and shows/hides modals using hooks from the same component. I am trying to abstract the modal to its own component and show/hide it from a parent component. Why do refs exist if I shouldn't use them?

Comment: It's not really that you "shouldn't" use refs, but if you find yourself using a lot of refs and other DOM manipulation, you're doing it wrong. They're not meant to be used so loosely.

Comment: `I don't understand how to manipulate the child's state without having a reference to it somehow` What you do is use a state in the parent and pass it down as prop.

Comment: @MattU Just to be clear, I never said that one "shouldn't" use refs. They clearly have a purpose. They just aren't necessary in this specific case here.

Comment: @ChrisG No worries, I was actually responding to Vrans with that comment, clarifying what I thought you meant. I agree that they are necessary in this case.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do refs exist if I shouldn't use them?

From the official doc [reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs), it mentioned about a few good use cases for refs:

1. Managing focus, text selection, or media playback.
2. Triggering imperative animations.
3. Integrating with third-party DOM libraries.

But we should not over-use refs because it is just an **imperative** way React.js exposed for the cases which couldn't be done in **declarative** way.
In most cases, sticking with the typical data-flow is just fine and we should avoid talking to DOM-elements directly in an imperative way.

> To use bootstrap modals in React, this [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modals-live) was always fine with me which is super easy to use and manage state whether inside the modal component itself or from the parent component.

Also, we should try to avoid using **show()** or **hide()** functions which are imperative, rather than that, we should use **props** as reactjs clearly mentioned [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modals-live)

> Though if you want to stick with your current approach,

**useRefs** is the way to get rid of **getElementById**. When you are trying to get refs of the element in the child component, you can use **forwardRef** API. [Read More](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components)

Comment: How would you then change the child's visibility using React Bootstrap? I don't understand how to manipulate the child's state without having a reference to it somehow

Comment: This is how they show/hide modals, so you can use `useState` to change the state of the modal. If you need to change visibility of the modal defined in the child component, you can define state in the parent and pass `state` value and `setState` function to the children so that the modal inside the children can get reference to change the status of itself.

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modals-live